# Css set size of elements in array dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array of elements, they have the tag class='element'.  How can I dynamically set the height of each element when they load?  When I try to set

```
$('.element').css('height',sizeOfContent+'px');
```

it changes the height of each .element

Comment: where is the code for sizeOfContent ?

Comment: Can you explain again what you want to do because what you said you want to do is what you appear to be doing

Comment: every time I create an element I want to size it specifically to the size of the content inside of the element.  When I call the snippet above it resets the height of every .element to the size of the given sizeofcontent

Comment: have you tried this CSS `height:auto;`?

Comment: I want each .element to have its own height as a function of its own content

Comment: @AH - I provided an example of that in my answer , you still have never gave code for how you set sizOfContent

Comment: it would be useful to edit your question giving an example

Comment: How is each .element created? Can you show this? One line of code is not enough. "I have an array of elements" is this in javascript? What does it look like? How is sizeOfContent derived?

Comment: You keep responding to comments , but not adding any code

Comment: What about not setting the height at all? Is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your question literally and with an idea based on your limited markup:

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfHhz/)

**HTML**

```html
<div id="box1" class="element"></div>
<div id="box2" class="element"></div>
<div id="box3" class="element"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px dashed black;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**JS**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Grab all elements on the page with classname '.element'
    var myElements = $('.element');

    // These are the sizes we need to change dynamically.
    // As seen in jsFiddle CSS panel, the original height for the above classname is 50px;
    var sizeOfContent = [ "100", "200", "300"];

    // Here, we run a .each() iteration and use the zero indexed value to match the corrisponding height as provided in variable sizeOfContent.
    $(myElements).each(function(index) {

        // Activate the console.log to view results in the browers console.
        //console.log( this );

        // jQuery css will automatically use pixle value when not specified
        $(this).css('height', sizeOfContent[index]);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you were looking to do ?  Set each `.element` to a specific height ?    `sizOfContent` will be set this way for each element , you didn't provide the code for how your setting sizOfContent - so I put it in a comment here

```
$.each('.element' , function(){
   var sizeOfContent = // dynamically set sizOfContent
// maybe something like this..
// var sizOfContent = $(this).parent().height();
// ** you wouldn't need an each loop just set to parents height, but you see how it can be dynamically set    
   $(this).css('height',sizeOfContent+'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$('.element')` is catching ALL elements with that class. That's what it does. You need a unique identifier, e.g. `$('#element1')` But because you're not telling us anything  about how these elements are created, what `sizeOfContent` is or how it's derived it's impossible to offer a solution in code, so here it is in words.

I can only assume you're iterating through the array you mentioned, so

If you're creating the objects and appending to the page, add `.css('height',sizeOfContent+'px');` to the jQuery chain where  something like `.appendTo('body')` will exist or give them an ID each and use `$('#element' + i).css('height',sizeOfContent+'px');`

```
$.each(thearray, function(i,data){ // or perhaps for (i in thearray) {
    var sizeOfContent= some formula;
    div=$('<div class="element">').appendTo('#somewrapper').css('height',sizeOfContent+'px');
});
```

With so little info it's impossible to answer.